# open command works only as sudo

Tags: filezilla

I am using Filezilla on Ubuntu which suddenly became unable to connect to a usual remote ftp server anymore.

I noticed that Filezilla try's to run:

```
open "user@server" 22
```

so I tried executing it on a terminal:

```
open "user@server" 22
```

which gives:

> Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console

However, using `sudo` gives:

```
sudo open "user@server" 22
```

seems to work ok.

Is there a file that `open` uses that its permissions needs to be changed??

Answer (score 1):

They are two different things

When you see an FTP client like filezilla using the command 'open user@server 22' that is happening *inside* an FTP session - the terminal equivalent of that would be

```
$ ftp
ftp> open <user@server> 22
```

When you execute the 'open' command itself directly in the terminal, without starting an ftp session first, what you're actually getting is the openvt program - which tries to execute a command on a numbered 'virtual terminal' (hence the message about "getting a file descriptor referring to the console")

See `man open` and `man ftp` for full usage details